# Where can I find the specification for xib files?

Tags: iphone, xib

We have developed a mobile app development toolkit which currently allows graphical designing of phone UI and generating applications for android mobiles. Now I am attempting to generate iPhone code out of the same specifications. The objective-c code is not a problem, but the XIB format used for UI design is hard to decrypt. Is there a specification document for the XIB file format? Any reference would be helpful. Alternately, is it possible to create the UI layout programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create UI Layout programmatically.

You have to set the frame and assign that frame to that User Interface elements.

And then after you have to add that element in to your view. It is so simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you point me to some good tutorial for programmatic dev of UI? Do have any resource on XIB specs?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to create the UI programmatically.

To do this, derive a class from `UIView`and create your subviews (`UILabel` and other components in your UI) in its constructor.
To show the subview, set its `Frame` property and add it by calling the `addSubview` method.

I think this link may be of use to you: [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH1-SW2).